# Proof about the invertibility of the power of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse, alternative-proof

So I have the following question. I have to prove if this statement is true or false. If it's true, I need to explain why. If it's false, I need a counterexample.

> If a square matrix $A$ satisfies $A^k=5{\rm{Id}}_k$ for some $k \geq 1$, then $A$ is invertible.

I can easily do this with determinants.

$\det(A^k)=5^k \det({\rm{Id}}_k)$

$\det(A)^k=5^k (1)$

Since $k \geq 1$ and $\det(A)^k \neq 0$, we have:

$\det(A)^k \neq 0$

$\det(A) \neq 0$

This implies that the statement is true.

However, is there a way to do this without determinants? Supposedly you have to use the properties of the invertibility of a square matrix.

For some background, the concept of span, linear combinations, RREF and transpose has been covered. Also, the conditions of invertibility $AB=BA={\rm{Id}}_n$ has been covered too.

Is there another way I could show this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$A \left(\frac15 A^{k-1}\right)=\left(\frac15 A^{k-1}\right)A=\rm{Id}.$$

Comment: Sorry I am having a bit of trouble following what you did. I see you divided by $5$ and factored an $A$ out but how does show anything?

Comment: @FutureMathperson It shows that $\frac15 A^{k-1}$ is the inverse of $A$. In other words, $\frac15 A^{k-1}$ is the $B$(the one you mentioned in the OP) you're looking for.

Comment: Yeah I got it now. I forgot that in the question, it specifically says that $\frac{1}{5} A^k = Id_n$ is given. So I don't need to explain why that is the inverse. It's given already.

Thanks!